# Getting error "the remote server returned an error: (404) not found." while using WCF service in client application

Tags: asp.net, wcf, asp.net-web-api

I have hosted my WCF on localhost. Here is my config file both service and client. I'm new to WCF. 
Why is it not working?
I am accessing method's json o/p to bind the gridview in client application.
But it is giving 404 error. Please look into my problem.

Service Config:

```
<system.servicemodel>
<services>
<service name="AdvaitWCF2.CustodianService" behaviorConfiguration="serviceBehavior">
<endpoint address="http://localhost:46292/CustodianService.svc" behaviorConfiguration="webBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="RestBinding" contract="AdvaitWCF2.ICustodianService">
<identity>
<dns value="localhost" />   

<endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpBinding"
address="mex" />
<host>
<baseaddresses>
<add baseAddress="http://localhost:46292/CustodianService.svc"/>

<bindings>

<webhttpbinding>
<binding name="RestBinding">
<readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="5242880" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" />
<security mode="None">

<behaviors>
<endpointbehaviors>
<behavior name="webBehavior">
<webHttp helpEnabled="true"/>
<servicebehaviors>
<behavior name="serviceBehavior">
<dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />

<serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
<serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />

<protocolmapping>
<add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https"/>

<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="false" />
```

Client Config:

```
<system.servicemodel>

<bindings>

<webhttpbinding>

<binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ICustodianService" >

<security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
<transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm" />

<client>
<endpoint 
name="ServiceReference1.CustodianService"
address="http://localhost:46292/CustodianService.svc" 
binding="webHttpBinding" 
contract="ServiceReference1.ICustodianService" 
behaviorConfiguration="webEndpoint" 
bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ICustodianService"
/>

<behaviors>
<endpointbehaviors>
<behavior name="webEndpoint">
<webHttp defaultBodyStyle="Wrapped" 
defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json" 
helpEnabled="true"/>
```

Comment: Are you launching the client with the same port each time, the one that matches the config?

Comment: Hi Ross. thank you for the reply.  my client application and WCF service both are hosted on localhost with different port

Comment: What I mean is if your service is listening at http://localhost:46292/CustodianService.svc but you are sending requests to http://localhost:83827/CustodianService.svc then that would be problematic.

Comment: @RossBush thank you for reply. I didn't get ur point. could you please help me out with if any changes that are required for both web config file.